# webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using the webview control in android to show the html content. But I face a problem that in webview I have to fix the height so thats why if html content contains less data then it wasted the space. Is there any solution to solve this problem that how can I show only same content as html has in the webview without any wasted space please help.

following xml i used to draw webview is this right? In this i give fix height to webview. if i am not giving fix height then it will show only 1 line data with scroll.

```
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llweb" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_height="500dip">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/helloWebView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_height="500dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "fill_parent" attribute for height and width in the webview.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your layout file on the `WebView`.

Comment: i put there android:layout_height="wrap_content" but there is a problem in that it shows only single line and rest comes after scrolling

Comment: @Amit Thaper: I don't understand. Could you please post a screenshot along with your layout XML?